# Combine items with same name into data frame

Tags: r, sum

if I have a table that looks like this (read in with read.table):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaef6.png

(The 0s are placeholders so I have a consistent number of rows)

Is there a way that I can add values with the same coresponding names (both values for a, all 4 values for l) and output it as a data frame? Also, the rows are not consistent (i.e. some columns have 4 a's, some have 2)

The result should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrCt5.png

I can assemble the data frame with a, b etc as row names and the columns once the values are summed, but I cannot figure out how to sum them according to their corresponding names.

This is how I am currently approaching this:

- `read.table()` for my table
- define empty `data.frame`
- use loop to extract and add column values by corresponding names? <-need help with this
- `cbind()` data frame and column I just generated
- continue through end of loop

-use row.names() and colnames() to change row and column names

My code so far:

```
setwd(wd)
read.table(dat.txt,sep="\t")->x
read.table(total.txt, sep="\t")->total
met<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r")
y<-data.frame(),
total[2,]->name
for g in 1:ncol(x){
  #column will be the column with the combined values according to name
  cbind(y,column)
}
row.names(y)<-met
colnames(y)<-name
write.table(y,file="data.txt",sep="\t")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: there are two values of a,b, etc in thing1, thing2, etc.  How would you like that to be represented in the final df?  does the second value of thing1 become thing3?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the results of dput(dfrm) where dfrm is the name of the object created by the read.table() operation.

Comment: I should have clarified: my data has more than 2 elements, there are roughly 120 such pairs of columns, so Thing 3 was just to illustrate that that I would continue to add more columns in

I have updated the question to include my R code so far.

Comment: so there are two values of a, b ,etc--I want to add all values of a and have that represented by a in the final df. I'm sorry if this is confusing

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could post `dat.txt` in a readable format.   Try `dput(x)` and copy+pasting the output

Answer (score 0):

you can break this down in to two parts:

(1) aggregate each column
(2) combine into a nice table

It can be nicely done using *apply.  I broke it down in for loops to make it easier to read

```
  ## sample df 
  df <- structure(list(thing1.met = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "g", "g", "h", "h", "i", "i", "j", "j", "k", "k", "l", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"), thing1 = c(-0.57, 0.42, -1.12, -0.5, -0.94, -1.87, -2.22, -0.33, 1.45, 0.46, -1.96, -0.35, -1.01, 0.72, 0.04, -0.21, 0.81, 1.28, -0.52, -1.19, 0.03, -1.71, 0.53, -1.96, 1.58, -0.1, -0.88, 0.92, 0.02, -0.91), thing2.met = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "g", "g", "h", "h", "i", "i", "j", "j", "k", "l", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"), thing2 = c(-0.06, -0.7, 0.16, 1.96, 0.78, -0.65, -0.17, 0.89, 0.68, -0.93, -1.44, -0.16, -0.52, -0.19, 1.15, -0.77, 0.69, -0.48, 1.75, 1.62, -0.68, -1.06, -1.2, 1.42, -0.2, 1.33, 2.24, 0.35, 2, -1.21), thing3.met = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "i", "k", "l", "l", "l", "m", "o", "o", "o", "p", "p", "p", "q"),     thing3 = c(1.27, 4.45, -2.42, -9.53, 3.33, 5.58, -2.94, 2.54,     12.44, 12.41, 7.6, 0.63, 5.67, -3.79, 12.28, 1.77, -0.4,     -0.04, 0.95, 4.93, 1.77, 0.37, -2.79, 2.36, 12.76, -5.4,     -4.73, -1.8, 0.52, -4.97)), .Names = c("thing1.met", "thing1", "thing2.met", "thing2", "thing3.met", "thing3"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")

  # create blank data frame
  results <- data.frame(row.names=met)

  # grab every other column
  cols <- seq(2, ncol(df), 2) 

  # aggregate over all m, over every pair of columns
  for (m in met) { 
    for (c in cols) {
      results[m, c/2] <- sum(df[,c][df[,c-1]==m])
    }
  }

  # clean up column names
  names(results) <- names(df)[cols]

  # final output
  results
```

example:

```
    > results
       thing1 thing2 thing3
    a  -0.15  -0.60   3.30
    b  -1.62   2.74  -9.53
    c  -2.81   0.07   8.91
    d  -2.55   0.68  -0.40
    e   1.91  -2.37  24.85
    f  -2.31  -0.68   8.23
    g  -0.29   0.96  15.53
    h  -0.17  -0.08   0.00
    i   2.09   1.27  -0.04
    j  -1.71   0.94   0.00
    k  -1.68  -1.06   0.95
    l  -1.43   0.22   7.07
    m   1.58  -0.20  -2.79
    n  -0.10   1.33   0.00
    o  -0.88   2.24   9.72
    p   0.92   0.35  -6.01
    q   0.02   2.00  -4.97
    r  -0.91  -1.21   0.00
```